# Reproducibility in Tensorflow with GPUs

Tags: python, tensorflow, random, tensorflow2.0, random-seed

Is it possible to achieve complete reproducibility of results in Tensorflow **using a gpu**? For example, if I do the following:

```
def set_seeds(seed=SEED):
    os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = str(seed)
    random.seed(seed)
    tf.random.set_seed(seed)
    np.random.seed(seed)
```

does this mean that I will achieve reproducible results? Otherwise, are there any additional required steps to achieving reproducibility, or is there naturally going to be some variation due to DL software implementation when using GPUs?

Comment: Related repository: https://github.com/NVIDIA/framework-determinism

Comment: If you want your TensorFlow program to run deterministically, you can mention below code near the start of your program. `tf.keras.utils.set_random_seed(1); tf.config.experimental.enable_op_determinism()`.For more details please refer [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/config/experimental/enable_op_determinism). Thanks!